# Multiple threads loading different classes using Class.forName("...")

Tags: java, multithreading, sqlite, deadlock, clickhouse

I have a scenario in which I thread should monitor Clickhouse and the other one should sqlite. In order to load driver classes, I am using `Class.forName("...")`. Since the threads are starting at a time. I think it is going under deadlock situation..

Here is the piece of code that describes the issue.

```
public class ch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        new OTTLCleaner().start();  // loading CH Driver
        new CHThr().start();        // loading CH Driver
        Spark.getInstance();        // loading Sqlite Driver
    }
}

class OTTLCleaner extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Inside OTTL");
            DBHelper.deleteTables();
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}

class CHThr extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Inside CHThr");
            DBHelper.CHConn();
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}

class Spark implements Runnable {

    private static class SingletonHelper {
        private static final Spark INSTANCE = new Spark();
    }

    public static Spark getInstance() {
        return SingletonHelper.INSTANCE;
    }

    private Spark() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Inside Spark");
            DBHelper.SqliteConn();
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
    }
}

class DBHelper {

    public static void CHConn() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver");
        System.out.println("CH");
        ...
    }

    static synchronized void SqliteConn() throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        System.out.println("spark");
        ...
    }

    public static void deleteTables() throws Exception {
        Class.forName("ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver");
        System.out.println("OTTl");
        ...
    }
}
```

I added `Thread.sleep` in between the threads, it works. It is a bad approach in real world. I may get one more thread which may needs to load diff driver in future. What is the good approach to implement this without fail?

Comment: You could perform the class-loading beforehand in your main method instead of each thread?

Comment: Those methods are generalized and they are used by some many other classes...

Comment: Please describe what happens. You say "it works" when you have a sleep, but what exactly doesn't work without the sleep? Class loading is perfectly safe to do from multiple threads concurrently.

Comment: JDBC no longer requires `Class.forName` to be called at all.   From [the java.sql documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/package-summary.html): “auto java.sql.Driver discovery -- no longer need to load a `java.sql.Driver` class via `Class.forName`”

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt without sleep, It is not able print either these statements "spark"or "OTTl" or throwing any Exceptions/errors and still the program will run for long time.  I think it is in a deadlock situation here. So If I put a little bit of sleep in between those threads, It is managing to load those classes and it will print those statements too..

Comment: @VGR, I completely agree and it is for `mysql`, but I am using `mysqlite`

Comment: If you’re using [this driver](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc), you don’t need `Class.forName`.

Comment: @VGR, You are right, I'll do that. My question is what if we have some other drivers in that place...? Why the program is pausing? and what is the way to avoid this problem?

Comment: Having more than one JDBC driver in the classpath is very rare.  In fact, I’m not sure I’ve ever heard of anyone deliberately doing that.